# How to include credentials using bitbucket webhooks

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks, bitbucket-cloud

I am using this interface:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

If I want to ping our Jenkins server, we need credentials to do, for example with cURL it would look like:

```
curl -u ${user}:${password} http://jenkins.teros.io/job/demo/build?token=demo_interos_token
```

so is there a way to pass creds somehow with the webhook interface or maybe in the query parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I created a middleman server, and Bitbucket can ping our server with creds in the url and we forward request to Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to give the credentials as part of the URL:

```
http://<user>:<password>@jenkins.teros.io/job/demo/build?token=demo_interos_token
```

This is based on [RFC-1738](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738#section-3.1) which defines the **URL Syntax**, and specifically the **Common Internet Scheme Syntax**.